# javascript + django - typeError: X is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django, p5.js

I'm using p5.js to do some drawing using data from json fed by my Django backend.  I have a my draw function defined at the base level of my html doc in the script element like so:

```
function draw(json) {

  if (json["leaf_text"]) {
    stroke(100)
    ellipse(json["leaf_center_x"], json["leaf_center_y"], json["leaf_height"], json["leaf_width"]).rotate(json["leaf_rotate"]);
  }
  if (json["twig_text"]) {
    stroke(100);
    console.log("drawing twig....");
    line(json["twig_base_x"], json["twig_base_y"], json["twig_tip_x"], json["twig_tip_y"]);
  }
  if (json["branch_text"]) {
    stroke(150);
    line(json["branch_base_x"], json["branch_base_y"], json["branch_tip_x"], json["branch_tip_y"]);
    console.log("x1 " + json["branch_base_x"]);
    console.log("x2 " + json["branch_base_y"]);
    console.log("y1 " + json["branch_tip_x"]);
    console.log("y2 " + json["branch_tip_y"]);

  }
  if (json["trunk_text"]) {
    stroke(255);
    line(json["trunk_base_x"], json["trunk_base_y"], json["trunk_tip_x"], json["trunk_tip_y"]);
  }
}
```

This function is called upon receipt of a successful ajax response as follows.  My problem is, I get a error in the js console because of the draw function.

```
TypeError: json is undefined
```

My understanding is that (please correct me where I am wrong) the 'draw' function is agnostic concerning whether or not 'json' exists or not and will wait and see what sort of object it is passed before it begins complaining that the parameter is not defined.  Is this not the idea of a function in javascript??  I must be missing something.  If this is the case, why would it complain that json is not defined?

```
if (json["leaf_text"]) {
  $("#grow").click(
    function(e) {
      console.log("attempting ajax...");
      e.preventDefault();
      var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
      var open_parens = ($("#txt").val()).indexOf("(");
      var close_parens = ($("#txt").val()).indexOf(")");
      var child = $("#txt").val().slice(0, open_parens);
      var parent = $("#txt").val().slice(open_parens + 1, close_parens);

      $.ajax({
          url: window.location.href,
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
            child: child,
            parent: parent,
            mode: "grow"
          },
          success: function(json) {
            setup();
            draw(json);
            ...
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
          console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }

      });
  });
```

Comment: Did you verify that you receive `json` in your success handler? Otherwise, is it possible that `setup()` references `json` somewhere?

Comment: @sthzg   I do verify it and no, it isn't referenced in setup().  Actually the json is working when I click the 'grow' button as it should, but when I reload the page I get the typeError in the console.

Comment: In the developer tools next to the type error should be a link to exactly the line in the script that causes the exception. Additionally, under the tab `Sources` in Chrome there is a button `Pause on exceptions` (it's a pause icon). If you click that and then reload the page it should stop exactly where this exception is thrown. Maybe this could help isolating the exact place in the code where this happen.

Comment: didn't notice the if block before the last edit... (just before the $("#grow") handler). is this a copy+paste error?

Answer (score 0):

If you use import called json, you should use different name as parameter for draw function (for example: draw(json_bar) or, in import, re-name json (for example: import json as json_foo).